# general way to proxy 'GET', 'POST' and 'DELETE' in flask

Tags: python, flask

Currently we proxy the call to another service. For that we check if `request.method` is `GET`, we use `request.get(url)`, and if `request.method` is `POST`, we use `request.post(url)`. Is there a cleaner implementation to handle such usage?

```
@app.route('/<path:url>', methods=('GET', 'POST'))
def foo(url):
    if check_token():
        req_url = "http://localhost:8081/{}?{}".format(url, request.query_string.decode('utf-8'))
        if request.method == 'GET':
            req = requests.get(req_url, stream=True)
        elif request.method == 'POST':
            req = requests.post(req_url, stream=True)
```

Comment: `req = getattr(requests, request.method.lower())(req_url, stream=True)`

Answer (score 0):

You can implement the two calls in two separate methods. Each method should have only type of method allowed.

```
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)



@app.route('/', methods=(['GET']))
def foo():
    return "get"


@app.route('/', methods=(['POST']))
def bar():
    return "post"
```